# Как прочитать обьект в массиве?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть обьект, в котором 7 массивов и в них по 10 обьектов, мне нужно выводить каждый массив с его 10 обьектами при клике.

```
    let sum = 0;
    let num = 0;
    let obj = {};

    json.forEach(() => {
        if(json.length < num){
            // При вызове console.log(obj) выводиться такая строка
            // {
            //   [{},{},{},{}],
            //   [{},{},{},{}],
            //   [{},{},{},{}]
            // }
            // Мне нужно прочитать те обьекты, которые внутри массива, при  
            // каждом клике на кнопку будет по отдельности выводиться каждый
            // массив с его внутренними обьектами
        }
        else{
            sum = num;
            num = num + 10;
            obj[num] = json.slice(sum, num);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать так:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn')

let obj = {
"arr1": [{value: 'arr1 Value1'}, {value: 'arr1 Value2'}, {value: 'arr1 Value3'}],
"arr2": [{value: 'arr2 Value1'}, {value: 'arr2 Value2'}, {value: 'arr2 Value3'}],
};
let newArr = Object.entries(obj);

let counter = 0;
let printValues = () => {
if(counter < newArr.length){
 newArr[counter][1].map(item => console.log(item.value))
}
counter++;

}

btn.addEventListener('click', printValues)
```

```html
<button class="btn">Прочитать</button>
```